# td colspan width not working

Tags: html, css

```css
table 
{
    width: 100%;
}
td:first-child
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I do not quite understand why the first `td` is not 100px wide and how can I do it exactly 100px with no JS?

Comment: I guess you meant `tr:firstchild` ?

Comment: No, I meant `td:first-child`. Please look in IE F12 tools - this style is okay, but it is ignored.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting the table width to 100%?  What do you expect to happen to the other two columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to remove the `colspan` to get this to work, as other's are suggesting, although that might be a valid/better idea, if it is not needed (in your example it isn't, since there is only one row, but perhaps this is for another situation where you need it)

You can use `table-layout: fixed;` to get it to respect your value.
I also added `padding: 0;` , to get the exact with down from `102px` to `100px`, just for neatness sake:

```css
table 
{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}
td:first-child
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This one works perfectly. I also added two `<col style="width: XXpx;" />` tags to adjust other row widths. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjqgxzu5/) Remove `colspan=2` this multiplies your width value from your css.

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table 
{
  width: 100%;
}
td:first-child
{
  width: 100px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```css
table 
{
    width: 100%;
}
tr td:first-child
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```